# Nested xml tag traversal using freemarker

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I am a newbee in freemarker and have a requirement where I need to traverse, the recursive nodes in xml using free marker.

Here is the example of sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Order>
               <OrderNumber>100001</OrderNumber>
               <Source>XYZ</Source>
               <OrderSublineNumber>7</OrderSublineNumber>
               <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
               <OrderlineInstance>125</OrderlineInstance>
               <Lob>MOB</Lob>
                <Order>
               <OrderNumber>100001</OrderNumber>
               <Source>XYZ</Source>
               <OrderSublineNumber>7</OrderSublineNumber>
               <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
               <OrderlineInstance>125</OrderlineInstance>
               <Lob>MOB</Lob>
                         <Order>
               <OrderNumber>100001</OrderNumber>
               <Source>XYZ</Source>
               <OrderSublineNumber>7</OrderSublineNumber>
               <OrderSublineType>ADD</OrderSublineType>
               <OrderlineInstance>125</OrderlineInstance>
               <Lob>MOB</Lob>
                        </Order>
               </Order>
    </Order>
```

The Freemarker i tried to implement it:

```
 <#macro test>
<ModifyRequest xmlns="http://soa.comptel.com/2011/02/instantlink">
      <RequestHeader>
       <NeType>BST</NeType>
      <OrderNo>${orderSubline.orderNo}</OrderNo>
      <ReqUser>${orderSubline.source}</ReqUser>
   </RequestHeader>
   <RequestParameters>
      <Parameter name="ACT_CODE1" value="${orderSubline.orderSublineNumber}"/>
      <Parameter name="REQ_TYPE" value="${orderSubline.orderSublineType}" />
      <Parameter name="ORDER_INSTANCE" value="${orderSubline.orderlineInstance}" />
     <Parameter name="LOB" value="${orderSubline.lob}"/>
   </RequestParameters>
  </ModifyRequest>
   </#macro>
  <@test/>
```

This is giving me the last `<ORDER>` tag values, where as I have a requirement to iterate all the nested xml `<ORDER>` tags. Please suggest me how can I achieve this by using freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is strange as the elements start with capital letter in the XML, but not in the FTL. So I'm not sure how the XML was exposed to FreeMarker in that project. Anyway, I suppose `orderSubline` is part of the data-model (top level variables) and corresponds to the top `Order` element. Instead of getting the `Order` element from the data-model inside the macro, you could pass the `Order` element to render as a parameter to the macro. Like `<#macro test orderSubline>` and then `<@test orderSubline />`. Thus, inside the macro the macro can call itself for a nested `Order` like:

```
<#if orderSubline.order[0]??>
  <@test orderSubline.order />
</#if>
```